# Xcode: Warning about App icon after Archiving app

Tags: xcode

I have a problem and I searched the whole internet, but couldn't find the right solution.

I want to Archive my app, everything gone well, but every time I get a error:

[image: The warning from Xcode about the images]

See here what the error says.

I have already tried a lot, like renaming the Icon files and putting them in my Info.plist, but it all did not work.
This is really frustrating, does someone has the same problem and found a solution? Or can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have icons with those dimensions?

Comment: Try this select the app icon in xcode files pane in left side and in the right side change type from png to icon.

Comment: Look in your Build Settings, make sure they're located in the boxes within as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open your [APP-NAME]-Info.plist with right mouse button and choose "Open As" -> "Source Code" then search for

```
<string>Appicon40x40</string>
<string>Appicon60x60</string>
```

and remove this lines.

If you really want them on your app check if the file name is correct (aren't you missing the .png part?)

It should work now.

Comment: Can't find that strings in the .plist

Comment: @user2578311 Don't you have the Info.plist file either? This information needs to be on any plist file because thats the way you can configure the app on XCode

Comment: I found a solution, I named the two Icon files for iOS 7 "AppIcon40x40.png" and "AppIcon60x60"